# RSA decryption suddenly went wrong, which was normal before

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, bouncycastle, sqlcipher

Before using this code for rsa decryption, running on the server everything is fine, but suddenly an error, and stopped running.

```
Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
        rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", "BC");
        String key = getKeyString();
        Reader privateKeyReader = new StringReader(key);
        PEMParser privatePemParser = new PEMParser(privateKeyReader);
        Object privateObject = privatePemParser.readObject();
        PrivateKey privateKey;
        if (privateObject instanceof PEMKeyPair pemKeyPair) {
            JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider("BC");
            privateKey = converter.getPrivateKey(pemKeyPair.getPrivateKeyInfo());
        } else {
            throw new KeyException("rsa key error");
        }

        rsa.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);


        byte[] decodeKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptRandomKey);
        byte[] utf8 = Decipherer.rsa.doFinal(decodeKey);

        return new String(utf8, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

exception:

```
org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.util.BadBlockException: unable to decrypt block
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.CipherSpi.getOutput(Unknown Source) ~[bcprov-jdk15on-1.64.jar:1.64.0]
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.CipherSpi.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source) ~[bcprov-jdk15on-1.64.jar:1.64.0]
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2205) ~[?:?]
    at com.pjcy.pullwechatmsg.Decipherer.decryptRSA(Decipherer.java:56) ~[getwechatmsg.jar:?]
    at com.pjcy.pullwechatmsg.Decipherer.decrypt(Decipherer.java:63) ~[getwechatmsg.jar:?]
    at com.pjcy.pullwechatmsg.ChatSet.decrypt(ChatSet.java:48) ~[getwechatmsg.jar:?]
    at com.pjcy.pullwechatmsg.Dispatcher.store(Dispatcher.java:57) ~[getwechatmsg.jar:?]
    at com.pjcy.pullwechatmsg.Dispatcher.start(Dispatcher.java:41) ~[getwechatmsg.jar:?]
    ^C
```

Comment: If it worked before and then *suddenly* doesn't work anymore, it might be the data. Post test data that can be used to reproduce the problem (non-productive key pair, ciphertext, plaintext that should result after decryption). Also, revise the code so that it is executable (currently unknown methods and types are used, see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Comment: There should be more information in the stack trace, including the wrapped exception(s) that contain the needed details. For example, the wrapped exception is either an `InvalidCipherTextException` or an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. And then perhaps that exception in turn wraps another one. These details can be critical to zeroing in on the problem.

Comment: Yes, you are. Yes, I have tried, and a different server will work, but not this one. The app does not rely on external data, and the root cause of the problem has not been found yet. I'm going to use docker, and docker will work fine.
Thank you very much for your help!